# Forge Viewer: Show bottom toolbar and markups at the same time

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm developing a tool that allow's several users to add markups to the same autocad drawings. I also want the users to be able to use the bottom toolbar of the forge viewer to hide/show layers and the properties popup.

The markup extension is good to add svg markups, however it hides the bottom toolbar of the forge viewer when entering the edit mode. It seams that the only way to show the bottom toolbar of the forge viewer is to call the `.hide()` method on the extension object which will hide the markups.

Is there a way to show the bottom toolbar and the markups at the same time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.Utils.showLmvToolsAndPanels(viewer)
```

However some of the built-in functionality (panning etc) disabled in markup mode (for compatibility reasons) which is why the toolbars were hidden away in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up making costum bottons for the things I wanted from the bottom toolbar. Namely the buttons to show the layers panel and properties panel.

Comment: Hi, can you share some example on how to add a `Markup Comment` at the bottom just like in this example: https://boranora3.autodesk360.com/g/shares/SH919a0QTf3c32634dcffbc8ab8354b3fdd3