# Autodesk Forge Viewer - show markups all the time

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

We are using the Forge viewer to show both 2D and 3D models. For the 2D models, we would like to be able to show markups all the time, like you can with the viewer inside BIM360.

I tried the solution mentioned here: [Forge Viewer: Show bottom toolbar and markups at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075628/forge-viewer-show-bottom-toolbar-and-markups-at-the-same-time/56099698) - but I have not been able to get that to work. It seems like when I call:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.Utils.showLmvToolsAndPanels(viewer)
```

It hides the markups.

How is this done in BIM360? - are they using a custom viewer, where this has been enabled somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was able to get it to work with:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.Utils.showLmvToolsAndPanels(viewer)
```

See live sample [here](https://jsbin.com/sezusav/edit?html):
[image]

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I got it working now. My problem was that I was calling the showLmvToolsAndPanels too early. I had to wait until the core extension and the model had been loaded